# Change default logo of E-commerce site in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

As highlighted in the image below from where can I change the default image which appears in master page in Kentico 9 E-commerce site ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pages > Ecommerce site (root master page) > Logo webpart (editable image)

Note: Please note sample sites are not supposed to be starter packs for your new site.

Comment: I wish those sample sites would only work with some weird setup so people couldn't use them as a production site!